# SignalR Basic Authentication with a javascript client

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, signalr

I'd like an example to how a Signalr javascript client can connect with a basic authentication ?

I didn't find any example about a javascript client.

In the siganlR server :

```
var listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;

var authoriser = new Authoriser();
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new AuthorizeModule(authorize, authorize));
```

And in the javascript client :

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost/signalr";
var hub = $.connection.signalr;
```

but with this "include"

```
<script src="http://localhost/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

The Server send me a Prompt to login password

But I'd like to send my own login password with an < input > for example...

Thanks !